# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Im creating a chrome extension for Rss reader in that im getting the above error. please help

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name": "Tutorialzine Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Making your first Google Chrome extension.",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js", "https://query.yahooapis.com"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "tutorialzine.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "<all_urls", 
        "http://localhost/",
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*", 
        "https://query.yahooapis.com"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; 'https://query.yahooapis.com';unsafe-inline; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var query = "SELECT * FROM feed WHERE url='http://feeds.feedburner.com/Tutorialzine' LIMIT 2";

    // Storing the seconds since the epoch in now:
    var now = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;

    // If there is no cache set in localStorage, or the cache is older than 1 hour:
    if (!localStorage.cache || now - parseInt(localStorage.time) > 1 * 60 * 60) {
        $.get("yahoo.js", function (msg) {

            // msg.query.results.item is an array:
            var items = msg.query.results.item;
            var htmlString = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                var tut = items[i];

                // Extracting the post ID from the permalink:
                var id = tut.guid.content.match(/(\d+)$/)[0];

                // Looping and generating the markup of the tutorials:

                htmlString += '<div class="tutorial">\
                            <img src="http://tutorialzine.com/img/posts/' + id + '.jpg" />\
                            <h2>' + tut.title + '</h2>\
                            <p>' + tut.description + '</p>\
                            <a href="' + tut.link + '" target="_blank">Read more</a>\
                            </div>';
            }

            // Setting the cache
            localStorage.cache = htmlString;
            localStorage.time = now;

            // Updating the content div:
            $('#content').html(htmlString);
        }, 'json');
    } else {
        // The cache is fresh, use it:
        $('#content').html(localStorage.cache);
    }
}
```

Error in jquery.min.js:

Jquery.min.js contains inline script what to do

```js
parentNode:d.removeChild(d.appendChild(s.createElement("div"))).parentNode===null,deleteExpando:true,checkClone:false,scriptEval:false,noCloneEvent:true,boxModel:null};b.type="text/javascript";try{b.appendChild(s.createTextNode("window."+f+"=1;"))}catch(i){}a.insertBefore(b,a.firstChild);if(A[f]){c.support.scriptEval=true;delete A[f]}try{delete b.test}catch(o){c.support.deleteExpando=false}a.removeChild(b);if(d.attachEvent&&d.fireEvent){d.attachEvent("onclick",function k(){c.support.noCloneEvent=
```

Comment: Your CSP has a few errors. It should read: `"script-src 'self' https://query.yahooapis.com; object-src 'self'"`. Also `https://query.yahooapis.com` is not necessary in `web_accessible_resources`; that array is for locally-hosted extension resources you want to be made available to regular, non-extension webpages.

Comment: Should not be tagged google-chrome-app, as CSP issues are different between apps and extensions.

Answer (score 24):

I also faced such type of problem when working with LinkedIn oAuth API.

I was using linkedIn API with following settings for cordova

**config.xml**

```xml
 <access origin="*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

**Meta Tag was**

```html
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

**Script**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script>
```

When i run the application on emulator its giving

[image]

**Fixed Problem to add uri into meta tag http://platform.linkedin.com like**

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://platform.linkedin.com ">
```

Comment: bare in mind using unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline is a security risk. You might be ok just using 'self' and 'unsafe-inline'.

Comment: 'unsafe-inline'  is a violation you might as well not have CSP

Comment: @George what is the alternate way of unsafe-inline

Comment: @ChiragPatel I believe although not certain, the best solution, is to use a hash string generated at build time, or a nonce value generated dynamically server side. But I may be completely wrong so I recommend researching trusted sources first. I'm not a security expert so mind my tentative language.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered it before, however, I'm not sure if your situation is the same as mine.
In my case, in the chrome extension, the html file is prohibited from running inline scripts. After I separate the script into a js file, the problem is solved.

Comment: Hi i have saml based login which has inline script causing CSP error. our web has csp set to 'sef' . how to bypass saml unsafe-inline issue

Answer (score 1):

It can be reason if you have this code in your htaccess. CommentOut this can fix your issue

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://www.example.com/"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error a couple of times in a few days, for no apparent reason (I forget the first "cause", but the second occurrance of this message was after a machine restart).

No amount of returning to previous working branches helped, nor adding the meta tags detailed in this question and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68340300/4616330) (basically the same).

So I **deleted `node_modules`**, and it's gone away now, and all is working well.  Maybe someone else's code is as random as mine...

Answer (score 0):

It's not such extension case but I had same error message on browser debug console. The error is solved by attaching script file at script tag.

I should upload html file with script on node js server. The script below gave the error message.

```html
<html>
...
<script>
...
//code

</script>
</html>
```

But attaching js file into script tag solved problem,

```html
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script-name.js"></script>

</html>
```

Seems attaching js file from the machine doesn't give the content security policy error not like just putting script tag below html file.

Comment: even doing this the error still popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust your build script in package.json to this

"build": "set \"INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false\" && react-scripts build"

the run npm run build or yarn build again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add  meta tag in head section
for non-secure url use below

for secure url use below

```
 <meta https-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;" />
```

flush cache

Issue will be resolved.
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Came to same issue just now.

I am getting similar console error with type="application/javascript"

```
 <script type="application/javascript">...</script>
```

but not with type="javascript"

```
 <script type="javascript">...</script>
```

Not sure if that helps someone, helped me.

Comment: I observed the same, and the only difference was that no error was thrown, but anyway the script was not executed. In author's case the directive's syntax is incorrect.