# Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

> I am trying to develop a chrome appplication in which i want to display a custom  Rss feeds but feeds are not get loaded and dispalying error like above.
>
> Error Details in which is displayed

```
Refused to load the script
 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'
 because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
 "script-src 'self'
 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js".

     Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js". 
 jquery.min.js:35

     Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'
 because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
 "script-src 'self'
 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js".

     Refused to load the script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=2&output=json&q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.tax2290.com%2Ffeed%2F&hl=en&callback=jsonp1373953012503'
 because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
 "script-src 'self'
 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js".
```

> manifest.json

```
{
      "name": "Tax New 2290",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "version": "1.1",
      "description": "Tax 2290",
    "web_accessible_resources": ["images/logo.png"],
      "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "19":"icon19.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png",
        "256": "icon256.png"
    },
     "browser_action":
    {
    "default_icon":"images/logo.png",
    "default_popup":"index.html"
    },

         "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>","http://www.tax2290.com","http://*/*", "https://*/*","http://*.google.com/"],
        "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js; https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js; object-src 'self'"

    }
```

> index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/feed.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/style.css" type="text/css"  />
<title>Chrome Popup</title>
</head>
```

> feed.js

```
        $(function() {
                var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
                $items.mouseover(function() {
                    $items.removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');

                    var index = $items.index($(this));
                    $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
                }).eq(0).mouseover();
            });


    $(document).ready(function () {  
       $('#divRss2').FeedEk({
            FeedUrl: 'http://blog.tax2290.com/feed/',
            MaxCount: 2,ShowDesc: true,
            ShowPubDate: true,
            DescCharacterLimit: 250
        });
    });


   > Please tel me how could avoid these errors and load the custom RSS feeds.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653384/refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-secur)

Comment: There are 4 Chrome things that can have a manifest.json file: Chrome App, Chrome Extension, Hosted App, and legacy packaged app. It would help if you could identify precisely which of these four you are trying to write. Your question mentions "chrome application," but the manifest you show isn't one for a Chrome App, so it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your "content_security_policy" has several problems.

1) The first is that you should remove the semicolon between the 1.4.1 and 1.9.1 jquery declarations. Multiple URLs should be separated with a single space only and no other characters.

2) The second is that you are trying to load this script "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=2&output=json&q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.tax2290.com%2Ffeed%2F&hl=en&callback=jsonp1373953012503" but you never allow that in your CSP.

3) And thirdly, it appears you need to allow inline scripts.

I would change your "content_security_policy" to look like this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'"
```

'unsafe-inline' should fix the "Refused to execute inline script" error.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ should allow both versions of jquery to load as well as your /ajarx/services/feed/load URL.

Comment: Downvote: `unsafe-inline` is ignored in Chrome Extensions

Answer (score 1):

If you build a packaged app, you can not load external script.
Your application must embed every scripts, styles or images.

Check this link to ensure you are following chrome app CSP rules: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: You are talking about packaged apps (while the question is obviously not about apps). Extensions can load external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

first try to remove this part from your manifest file

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js; https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js; object-src 'self'"
```

then download all of your external links to a local environment folder after that reference it there.

for example download
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
to your parent folder
and change your reference from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also I recommend moving all of your referencing from head tag to the bottom of body tag.